# Showing header and footer in CodeIgniter custom error pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter folder I have got custom error pages for each type of error in `application/views/errors/html` like error_404.php etc. So when I tried to update the layout and added `<?php  $this->load->view('header'); ?>` on top then it started to show me errors like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Exceptions::$load

Filename: html/error_404.php
```

So I want to know how can I make it to work? I also tried to extends the Exception class from CI_controller but still no luck. Please help me to add my custom header to my custom error page. Thanks.

PS: I want to clear that even if I use some how PHP's include() function but I also want to use base_url function for e.g.

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/iconmenu.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script> <br>
```

One more thing I want to clear that I am using **Codeigniter 3.0** which **provides** all error's templates but don't allow to use $this->load function.

Comment: If people dont know the answer they down vote it. If dont get it you can ask to clearify but down voting is not right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for the above error. Might be it's because of core libraries are not loaded in case error `404` is happened.

You can try another way. See `application/route.php` and there is an option to override the 404 url, `$route['404_override'] = '';`

Example: Create a method `error_404` in `Welcome` controller and update the route variable like  `$route['404_override'] = 'welcome/error_404';`, now you can use whole `helpers` / `libraries` etc.

See [routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#reserved-routes)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks I knew about that but I am concerned for 500/database error and I want to create template especially for that and unfortunately there is not route variable reserved for that.

Comment: I guess I need to use either .htaccess for this  or created a completely separate template with absolute URLs as in core php. CI does not provide any functionality  for this

Comment: Yes I believe that need to be handled in .htaccess